# Getting empty ListLogLogPlot from a Transpose

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, table

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 3 x'[t] Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] + Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, a'[t]/a[t] ==Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4], a[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 5.62883099311609}, {x, a}, {t,0,500}]
```

Here it is a numerical solution to a system of differential equations I solved. Particularly, I have defined

```
Ht = Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol
Et = x'[t] /. sol[[1]]
At = (Ht^4)/((Et*2*Pi)^2)
Nt = -2 (-D[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol,
    t]/(Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. 
    sol)^2) - D[-D[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol, t]/(Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /.sol)^2, t]/((Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol) (-D[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol, t]/(Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /.sol)^2))
Ut = a[t]*Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol
l = Ut /. t -> 30.339788815058
```

I want to get some values and place them in a table,

```
resultTable1 = Table[1 + Nt, {t, 30.339788815058, 144.728852417507}]
resultTable2 = Table[Ut/l, {t, 30.339788815058, 144.728852417507}]
```

Then, the next step is to plot them, so I defined

```
Transpose[{resultTable2, resultTable1}]
```

However, when I write and run

```
ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{resultTable2, resultTable1}]]
```

I do not get anything more than an empty plot, which is rare since there is no warning or error message on any step of the code. Which could be the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the result of `Transpose[{resultTable2, resultTable1}]`? Try `Dimensions[Transpose[{resultTable2,resultTable1}]]` and see what you get. This will explain why `ListLogLogPlot` does not know what to do with it.

Comment: @Nasser, `Transpose[{resultTable2, resultTable1}]` gives the pair List of pairs of each element from `resultTable2` and `resultTable1`. On the other hand, `Dimensions[Transpose[{resultTable2, resultTable1}]]` outputs `{115,2,1}}`.

Comment: That is right. You have 3D list of dimension `{115,2,1}`. If you look at  help for `ListPlot` for example, it can only accept 1D or 2D lists. Not 3D lists. same for `ListLogLogPlot` so your input has wrong dimensions.

Comment: @Nasser, and how do I flatten it to two dimensions? I am trying everything and do not see a way to make it

Comment: Try either `data=Transpose[{Flatten[resultTable1],Flatten[resultTable2]}];
ListLogLogPlot[data]` or `data=Transpose[{Flatten[resultTable2],Flatten[resultTable1]}];
ListLogLogPlot[data]` as I am not sure the semantics of your data. See if either one of these gives you what you wanted. Now `data` is 2D

Answer (score 1):

NDSolve gives a list of solutions. The get the first one you need ...[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPBzV.png)]:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 
      3 x'[t] Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] + 
      Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, 
    a'[t]/a[t] == Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4], 
    a[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 5.62883099311609}, {x, a}, {t, 0, 
    500}][[1]];
```

With this:

```
Ht = Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol;
Et = x'[t] /. sol;
At = (Ht^4)/((Et*2*Pi)^2);
Nt = -2 (-D[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol,
         t]/(Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. 
         sol)^2) - 
   D[-D[Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol, 
        t]/(Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. 
         sol)^2, t]/((Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/
           4] /. sol) (-D[
          Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol, 
          t]/(Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. 
           sol)^2));
Ut = a[t]*Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] /. sol;
l = Ut /. t -> 30.339788815058;
```

Then, to get the correct x values in the plot, you need to include x values in the data:

```
resultTable1 = 
  Table[{t, 1 + Nt}, {t, 30.339788815058, 144.728852417507}];
resultTable2 = 
  Table[{t, Ut/l}, {t, 30.339788815058, 144.728852417507}];
```

Then we can plot the data:

```
ListPlot[resultTable1]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[resultTable2]
```

[image]